# Representation of recurrence as a polynomial

Tags: recurrence-relations, galois-theory

I'm studying linear-feedback shift register generators. In those kinds of generators, there's this recurrence:
$$
b_i\equiv(a_{p}b_{i-p}+a_{p-1}b_{i-p+1}+\ldots+a_{1}b_{i-1})\,\, mod\,\,2
$$
In a book, it says that as the module is prime, then we can express that recurrence as the following polynomial:
$$
f(z)=z^p-(a_{1}z^{p-1}+\ldots+a_{p-1}z+a)
$$
over the Galois filed $\mathcal{G}(2)$ defined over the integers 0 and 1 with the addition and multiplication being defined in the usual way followed by a reduction modulo 2.

1. Can someone explain to me why the module needs to be prime?
2. In addition, it says that "an important result from the theory developed for such polynomials is that, as long as the initial vector of bs is not all 0s, the period of the recurrence is $2^p-1$ if and only if the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathcal{G}(2)$.

Note: the book I'm following is 'Random Number Generation and Monte Carlo Methods, Second Edition, by James E. Gentle, page 38,39.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This theory heavily relies on the theory of Galois fields (fields on a finite set), which enjoy suitable arithmetic properties. It turns out that the only possibly Galois fields have $m^p$ elements, where $m$ is a prime. $G(2)$ is the smallest Galois field.

The result 2. is a known theorem is the theory of Galois fields. It is invoked because a long period is desired, and $2^p-1$ has maximum length.

Comment: But what is that theorem? Does it have a name? Or do you have a reference?

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado: "Blahut, Theory and Practice of Error Control Codes", but you won't find it :-(

Comment: Does it only appear in that book? :/

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado: of course not. You will find it everywhere.

Comment: I will try to find that theorem then, thanks.